# Sound stops after few seconds app Unity on Android 13

Tags: unity-game-engine, playsound, android-13

I'm testing a Unity app on a virtual device (Pixel 4a API33) from Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1.

The application is only a background image and music (for testing).

Initially the black screen appeared after the splash screen. But I found the trick to select "Mute Other Audio Sources" in the "Player Settings/Other Settings"

Now the application starts correctly but after a few seconds (15 seconds or so) the sound stops.

This should not happen as the sound is programmed to repeat indefinitely.

There is no button, event or change. Nothing appears in the logcat, it is apparently normal.

This happens only in APIs 31, 32 and 33. In the previous ones it works correctly.

Anyone know what might be happening? Anyone know a solution?

Thank you.